# Converting class component to functional component TypeError: users.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

Making a employee directory and I'm trying to convert class component into functional component. The nav, search, and table will render but the call to the api isn't working. Getting a
`TypeError: users.filter is not a function` Here is the class component that works and the in progress functional component. I can't figure out what is different.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DataTable from "./DataTable";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import API from "../utils/API";
import "../styles/DataArea.css";

export default class DataArea extends Component {
  state = {
    users: [{}],
    order: "descend",
    filteredUsers: [{}]
  }

  headings = [
    { name: "Image", width: "10%" },
    { name: "Name", width: "10%" },
    { name: "Phone", width: "20%" },
    { name: "Email", width: "20%" },
    { name: "DOB", width: "10%" }
  ]

  handleSort = heading => {
    if (this.state.order === "descend") {
      this.setState({
        order: "ascend"
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        order: "descend"
      })
    }

    const compareFnc = (a, b) => {
      if (this.state.order === "ascend") {
        // account for missing values
        if (a[heading] === undefined) {
          return 1;
        } else if (b[heading] === undefined) {
          return -1;
        }
        // numerically
        else if (heading === "name") {
          return a[heading].first.localeCompare(b[heading].first);
        } else {
          return a[heading] - b[heading];
        }
      } else {
        // account for missing values
        if (a[heading] === undefined) {
          return 1;
        } else if (b[heading] === undefined) {
          return -1;
        }
        // numerically
        else if (heading === "name") {
          return b[heading].first.localeCompare(a[heading].first);
        } else {
          return b[heading] - a[heading];
        }
      }

    }
    const sortedUsers = this.state.filteredUsers.sort(compareFnc);
    this.setState({ filteredUsers: sortedUsers });
  }

  handleSearchChange = event => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    const filter = event.target.value;
    const filteredList = this.state.users.filter(item => {
      // merge data together, then see if user input is anywhere inside
      let values = Object.values(item)
        .join("")
        .toLowerCase();
      return values.indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
    this.setState({ filteredUsers: filteredList });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    API.getUsers().then(results => {
      this.setState({
        users: results.data.results,
        filteredUsers: results.data.results
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Nav handleSearchChange={this.handleSearchChange} />
        <div className="data-area">
          <DataTable
            headings={this.headings}
            users={this.state.filteredUsers}
            handleSort={this.handleSort}
          />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import DataTable from "./DataTable";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import API from "../utils/API";
import "../styles/DataArea.css";

const DataArea = () => {

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([{}]);
  const [order, setOrder] = useState("descend");
  const [filteredUsers, setFilteredUsers] = useState([{}]);


  const headings = [
    { name: "Image", width: "10%" },
    { name: "Name", width: "10%" },
    { name: "Phone", width: "20%" },
    { name: "Email", width: "20%" },
    { name: "DOB", width: "10%" },
  ];

  const handleSort = (heading) => {

    if (order === "descend") {
      setOrder((order = "ascend"));
    } else {
      setOrder((order = "descend"));
    }

    const compareFnc = (a, b) => {
      if (order === "ascend") {
        // account for missing values
        if (a[heading] === undefined) {
          return 1;
        } else if (b[heading] === undefined) {
          return -1;
        }
        // numerically
        else if (heading === "name") {
          return a[heading].first.localeCompare(b[heading].first);
        } else {
          return a[heading] - b[heading];
        }
      } else {
        // account for missing values
        if (a[heading] === undefined) {
          return 1;
        } else if (b[heading] === undefined) {
          return -1;
        }
        // numerically
        else if (heading === "name") {
          return b[heading].first.localeCompare(a[heading].first);
        } else {
          return b[heading] - a[heading];
        }
      }
    };

    const sortedUsers = filteredUsers.sort(compareFnc);
    setFilteredUsers({ filteredUsers: sortedUsers });
  };

  let handleSearchChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    const filtered = event.target.value;
    const filteredList = users.filter((item) => {
      // merge data together, then see if user input is anywhere inside
      let values = Object.values(item).join("").toLowerCase();
      return values.indexOf(filtered.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
    setFilteredUsers((filteredUsers = filteredList));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    API.getUsers().then((results) => {
      setUsers({
        users: results.data.results,
        filteredUsers: results.data.results,
      });
    });

  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <Nav handleSearchChange={handleSearchChange} />
      <div className="data-area">
        <DataTable
          headings={headings}
          users={filteredUsers}
          handleSort={handleSort}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default DataArea;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your `useEffect` hook where you shoehorn both `users` and `filteredUsers` into your `users` state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  API.getUsers().then((results) => {
    setUsers({
      users: results.data.results,
      filteredUsers: results.data.results,
    });
  });
}, []);
```

It should be

```
useEffect(() => {
  API.getUsers().then((results) => {
    setUsers(results.data.results);
    setFilteredUsers(results.data.results),
  });
}, []);
```

You want to populate both the `users` state, and separately the `filteredUsers` state.

An issue with setting the sorting order, you are mutating the `order` state:

```
if (order === "descend") {
  setOrder((order = "ascend")); // <-- mutates
} else {
  setOrder((order = "descend")); // <-- mutates
}
```

You can simply toggle between the two:

```
setOrder(order => order === 'ascend' ? 'descend' : 'ascend');
```

Another issue is at the end of your `handleSort` function:

```
const sortedUsers = filteredUsers.sort(compareFnc);
setFilteredUsers({ filteredUsers: sortedUsers });
```

This will nest the filteredUsers array, and also mutates the array in-place, it should probably use a functional state update to update from the previous state, use array.slice to make a copy, and then call sort.

```
setFilteredUsers(filteredUsers => filteredUsers.slice().sort(compareFnc));
```

Comment: That's works but when the page starts to render i get a failed compile and this error : ` Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`

Comment: Got it I put a comma instead of a semicolon.. Thank you so much friendo!

Comment: Awesome! Answer Accepted!  Thank you for the added feedback as well!! I would have never thought to use a ternary for toggling. Much appreciated and thank you again for the Help!

Comment: @KevinMillhouse If you convert/rename `order` to something like `orderAscend` and make it a boolean then toggling it becomes even simpler, `setOrderAscend(order => !order)` then just check `if (orderAscend) { .....`.

Comment: Damn thank you! Am I understanding this right does this work because the useState updates the state of the boolean in turn updating the order via that order parameter?

Comment: @KevinMillhouse Right, but since you are really working with booleans in the conditional test to decide how to sort (i.e. comparing to string literals) it is more clear to give the variable a better name (to indicate what it represents) and use directly. This pattern will help you avoid a class of bugs caused by typos, i.e. an error caused by misspelling a string literal like `if (order === 'acsend') ...`. Compilers/transpilers are great, but they can't catch spelling mistakes.

Comment: Noted and thank you once again! One last question I'm just getting started with react are there any resources you'd suggest to plus up my react game?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234352/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-kevin-millhouse).